# how remove .php extension just one file nginx

Tags: php, nginx, config

My Nginx config is:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri = 404;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass php-fpm:9000;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param REQUEST_URI $request_uri;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
    fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
}
```

`
Now I remove .php from my page for example:  exmaple.com/course.php to exmaple.com/course

add

```
location ~ /course {
 rewrite ^ /course.php
}
```

but any page url has course redirect to course.php

Comment: Try to append a dollor `/course$`

Comment: add $, but server has error:  This site can’t be reached

Comment: @RichardSmith = 
it is unacceptable. add ~,  i have page url example.com/john/course; this link redirect to course.php